# Transaction management of JPA and external API calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

I'm new to spring, started using spring boot for the project. We have an use case of implementing database changes and few external API calls as one transaction. Please suggest, is this possible with the spring @transactional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the API calls need to be part of the transaction?

If the answer is no, I would advise to use `TransactionTemplate.doInTransaction()` leaving the API requests outside of the Tx.

If you need to make the API requests inside a Tx, I would advise against it, you would be locking DB resources for the duration of those requests.

You can also search and find out more about the `eventual consistency` model.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Transactional` for multiple database changes as one transaction is of course doable with the annotation but not so much for the external API calls. You would have to implement some custom logic for that - there would have to be endpoints to undo your last actions and you would have to implement calling them manually in try-catch block for example. For example, if the external API call creates an item there would also have to be an endpoint to delete an item and so on.

So to summarise - using `@Transactional` annotation for implementing database changes as one transaction is fine, but not enough for external API calls.